# Data Manipulation - Get data from another column if `nan`

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

I have a Pandas DataFrame of 23 columns and 1119 rows.

Here is the issue, columns 13, 14, 20 and 21 are of float dtype.

If data in column 13 and 14 is `nan`, then they are present in 20 and 21, and vice versa.

I want to create a column, if value is missing, get from the other.

Example: column 13 and 14 is `nan` then get value from 20 and 21.

Here is what I came up with, I created a function and iterated using itertuples

```
def AP_calc(df):
    for i in df.itertuples():
        if i[20]==np.nan & i[21]==np.nan:
           pool = i[13] + i[14]
        else:
            pool = i[20] + i[21]
        return pool
```

then used an apply function but this does not work.

```
df["test"] = df[['AP in %','AP_M in %','FixP in €','FixP C in €']].apply(AP_calc,axis=1)
```

I have tried other methods too but not working, please help me out, please

Comment: share a sample of the dataframe, with only the four affected columns. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Comment: I just did, please check

Comment: You likely did not read @sammywemmy's link before you posted that, because that is not what was asked for. Please also read [Why not upload images of code on SO when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question) to see why.

Comment: Is column `20` called `FixP in €` or `AP in %` ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [`numpy.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) with mask created by [`Series.isna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isna.html):

```
m = df['FixP in €'].isna() & df['FixP C in €'].isna()
df["test"] = np.where(m, df['AP in %'] + df['AP_M in %'], df['FixP in €'] + df['FixP C in €'])
```

Or:

```
c1 = ['FixP in €','FixP C in €']
c2 = ['AP in %','AP_M in %']

m = df[c2].isna().all(axis=1)
df["test"] = np.where(m, df[c1].sum(axis=1), df[c2].sum(axis=1))
```

Alternative with selecting by positions with [`DataFrame.iloc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html):

```
c1 = [20,21]
c2 = [13,14]

m = df.iloc[:, c2].isna().all(axis=1)
df["test"] = np.where(m, df.iloc[:, c1].sum(axis=1), df.iloc[:, c2].sum(axis=1))
```

Comment: Is there a way I could contact you?

Comment: @A.JT - I have email in my profile. Only run code for email.

Comment: Just did, check your mailbox

Comment: Is there a way I could add € for the ones coming from df['FixP in €'] + df['FixP C in €'] and % from the ones coming from df['AP in %'] + df['AP_M in %']

Comment: @A.JT - Not sure if understand, do you need change number e.g. `20` to `20€` ?

Comment: exactly, after adding. Add € to the additions on the columns: 'FixP in €' and FixP C in € and % in the other two.

Comment: @A.JT - there are 3 solutions, what use with real data?

Comment: To the existing data I have. those ones with € are in Euro and the other column is in percentage

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208231/discussion-between-jezrael-and-a-j-t).

Answer (score 0):

Just let the columns fill the N/A places of each other:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'Bob': [10, 30, np.nan], 
                   'Alice': [13, np.nan, 40]})

df['Bob'].fillna(df['Alice'], inplace=True)
df['Alice'].fillna(df['Bob'], inplace=True)
```